# Random Split - removing one path

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

Sometimes JB is maddening. Is there a way to change your Random Split from having 3 paths to 2 paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is believed to be a once off action, and once the random path are chosen, it is not possible yet in UI to revert back to lower number of paths.

However, the work around would be:

**1)** Change the volume number to be as less as possible so the impact is low. for e.g A - 30%, B - 20% and C - 50% could be A - 40%, B - 59% and C - 1%.

**2)** Once you've changed the impact on C path - you could optionally put a join at the end of the split and back to A or B.

Again, above is my personal opinion and I am not aware of the risks or scenario and as per the question this is what the possible solution could be.

Comment: No worries @Daniel. upvote would be great :)